# wget download files simultaneously from the same directory

Tags: http, wget

I can't seem to find if you can do this with wget or not.

What I am trying to do is download a whole bunch of images from one folder on a web server where all the images are stored. I am wondering if i can have multiple runs of wget to download them quicker.

eg

```
instance 1 of wget is downloading file 1
instance 2 of wget is downloading file 2 
instance 3 of wget is downloading file 3 ...
```

and so on.

once an instance has finished I want it to move to the next file that hasn't started downloading yet. 
Is this even possible with wget?

Answer (score 0):

It's a question for your operating system.
For example :
If you are trying to run wget from command line, to launch wget and get
on linux you may add amp sign (&) at the end of your command.

```
"your wget command here" &
```

on windows you can type

```
start "your wget command here"
```

and a lot of other ways actually